# Error in JSON payload while trying to access google cloud speech api

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-platform

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",  
      "sample_rate": 16000,  
      "language_code": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://speechtotextapi/audio_file.flac"
  }
}
```

curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json \
 "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${API_KEY}"

Initially I converted the mp4 file to FLAC format and then uploaded it to the bucket. This is the api response.

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"sample_rate\" at 'config': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "config",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"sample_rate\" at 'config': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]

Comment: Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the properly formatted input as an array and then json encode it. For example, to send a file, base64encode it as "content" and submit to the API as shown:

$upload = base64_encode(file_get_contents(NAME_OF_YOUR_AUDIO_FILE));

"audio"     =>  array(
        "Content"       =>  $upload,
    )

Comment: This is the response im getting after modifying the request

curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @request.json \
"https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize?key=${API_KEY}"

{ "name": "283477145540444562" }.

I'm not seeing any text/string as output. Any idea as to what is happening?

Comment: Just found out that I will get the actual text using the GET request
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/YOUR_OPERATION_NAME?key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

change attribute sample_rate in sampleRateHertz
try this:

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",  
      "sampleRateHertz": 16000,  
      "language_code": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://speechtotextapi/audio_file.flac"
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).